# How Eve-NG console selection works?

Tags: javascript, python

[Eve-NG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AA8Kh.png)

Hi

I am using a network simulator - Eve-NG. 
The login box has a drop-down menu to select native or html5 console.
With a native console, device connections are opened with 3rd party apps like Putty
With hmtl5 console, the connections open in a browser tab.

When doing API calls to Eve-NG server the response is received from html5 console. 
In Eve-NG docs there is no mention of how to change the console in API calls.

My question is, is it possible to force the http get response to come from native console?

GET requests for both consoles in Chrome development tools is identical. 
I guess it's selected on login?

I am using Python with Requests.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0):

So.. when I was logging in with valid credentials .. dev tools in chrome didnt show the POST. I tried with invalid creds and saw the POST request with creds data. 
So.. I looked like html5 is disable on login.

{username: "admin", password: "admin", html5: "-1"}

[dev-tools-eve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4Wxw.png)

Tried that in Python and it worked as expected.

Thanks a lot, StackOverflow .. posting question made me think differently